# Inheritance in webapp2

Tags: python, inheritance, webapp2

I have a base class defined like this:

```
class BaseRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #Either loads pages from memcache or from ndb (or from a jinja template) and then caches them.
    def memcache_loader(page_name):
        #implementation not shown, you could just replace this with "return jinjatemplate"
        pass
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(self.memcache_loader(self.__class__.__name__).render())
```

Then, I have a class that inherits from `BaseRequestHandler`:

```
class Index(BaseRequestHandler):
    pass
```

The thing is, I would expect the `Index` class to inherit the `get` method from `BaseRequestHandler`, but it doesn't, and when I visit Index (which is mapped to `\`), it doesn't load the index page. Why isn't the inheritance mechanism working?

Comment: On Python 2.7, try adding to Index() a `def __init__(self):
        super(Index, self).__init__()` and see if any changes occur.

Comment: Override the get() method in Index to see if it's being called, have it write something out.  Also, change the BaseRequestHandler's get() method to simply write out `self.__class__.__name__` to see what it is.  Don't forget about `logging` to help you see variables!